# Jenkins Git Plugin does not receive posted Parameters

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I am trying to use Node.js to programmatically build Jenkins jobs that take Git parameters.

I am sending the parameters as post data, as shown below. However, no matter what value I assign to `ref`, Jenkins runs the build with the default parameter value (specified in the job's configuration). I have tried passing in the parameters as query strings in the URL, but that also did not work.

I am using Jenkins v1.651.1 and Node v6.2.0.

```
var jobOptions = {
    url: requestedJobObject.url + 'build',
    method: 'POST',
    port: 8080
};

// parameters = { "name": "ref", "value": "origin/master" }
if (!_.isEmpty(parameters)) {

    var jsonParametersString = JSON.stringify({"parameter": parameters});
    var parameterParam = encodeURIComponent(jsonParametersString);
    parameters.json = parameterParam;

    jobOptions.headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': querystring.stringify(parameters).length
    };

    jobOptions.url += 'WithParameters';

    postData = querystring.stringify(parameters);
}

// jobOptions contains auth field & separates url into hostname and path
// makes an http request to jobOptions and calls req.write(postData)
makeRequest(jobOptions, callback, responseCB, postData)
```

makeRequest makes an http request:

```
function makeRequest (object, callback, responseCB, postData) {
    var accumulator = '';

    var parsedUrl = u.parse('//' + object.url, true, true);

    var options = {
        hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
        port: object.port || 8080,
        path: parsedUrl.path,
        method: object.method || 'GET',
        auth: getAuthByHost(parsedUrl.hostname)
    };

    if (object.headers) {
        options.headers = object.headers;
    }

    var response = null;
    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        response = res;

        res.on('data', function (data) {
            accumulator = accumulator + data.toString();
            res.resume();
        });

        res.on('close', function () {
            // first assume accumulator is JSON object
            var responseContent;
            try {
                responseContent = JSON.parse(accumulator);
            }
            // if not object, use accumulator as string
            catch (err) {
                responseContent = accumulator;
            }

            callback(responseContent, response.statusCode);


            if (responseCB) {
                responseCB(res);
            }

        });
    });

    req.on('close', function () {

        // first assume accumulator is JSON object
        var responseContent;
        try {
            responseContent = JSON.parse(accumulator);
        }
        catch (err) {
            responseContent = accumulator;
        }

        callback(responseContent, response.statusCode);

        if (responseCB) {
            responseCB(response);
        }

    });

    if (postData) {
        req.write(postData);
    }

    req.end();
}
```

Comment: can you share your makeRequest method?

Comment: @Tizkiko updated the question to contain makeRequest function

Comment: See that the GitLab plugin does not accept arbitrary parameters. There is an issue open for it: https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/912 that deserves to be upvoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this, it works for me:

```
var auth = 'Basic yourUserToken';
var jobOptions = {
    url:'jenkinsHostName:8080/jenkins/job/jobName/' +'build',
    method: 'POST',
    port: 8080
};

var parameter = {"parameter": [{"name":"ref", "value":"origin/master"}]};
var postData;
if (!_.isEmpty(parameter)) {

    var jsonParametersString = JSON.stringify(parameter);
    jobOptions.headers = {
        'Authorization':auth,
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    };

    jobOptions.url += '?token=jobRemoteTriggerToken';
    postData = "json="+jsonParametersString;

    console.log("postData = " + postData);
}   
var callback;
var responseCB;
makeRequest(jobOptions, callback, responseCB, postData) ;
```

It is based on your code. I removed the querystring - it seems that it returned an empty string when performed on the parameters object. I change /buildWithParameters to /build - it didn't work the other way.

In addition, verify that when you pass the 'Content-Length' in the header, it doesn't truncated your json parameters object (I removed it ).

also note that I used the user API token, that you can get at http://yourJenkinsUrl/me/configure and click the "Shown API Token" button. [image]

Comment: Did the above work for git parameters? When I run the above (with hardcoded parameter and jobRemoteTriggerToken), Jenkins is still not registering that I am passing in git parameters at all. One difference is that I am using Github authentication with Jenkins instead of the user API token

Comment: Update: when I run the above code with a string parameter, Jenkins registers that I am trying to pass in a parameter, but does not register the value that I pass in. On the web client, the parameters box says KEY (the parameter name), with an empty box next to it (empty value field).

Comment: @JanetC. do you still have that issue? did you remove the content length?  also note that I used /build and not /buildWithParameters

Comment: aha! Changing /buildWithParameters to /build fixed it!

Comment: @JanetC.great! I added a note in the answer

Comment: I'm facing the same issue where my parameters are going empty. However if i send parameters in URL it works absolutely fine. Can i know what is wrong/missing in my request, curl -X POST -H http://XX.XX.XX:8080/job/XXX/buildWithParameters \
  --user "Ashwin:XXXX" \
  --data-urlencode='{"parameter": [{"name":"param1", "value":"123"}, {"name":"param2", "value":"high"}]}'

Comment: I was able to rectify the issue. I had used buildWithParameters once i changed it to build, the request is going as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about this, as I don't know Node.js -- but maybe this fits: the [Jenkins remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) indicates that the parameter entity in the json request must point to an *array*, even if there's just one parameter to be defined.

Does the change below fix the problem (note the angle brackets around `parameters`)?

```
[...]
var jsonParametersString = JSON.stringify({"parameter": [parameters]});
[...]
```