# How to build with parameters in Jenkins from Gitlab push?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, webhooks, jenkins-pipeline

I have GitLab Community Edition 8.15.2 successfully trigger pipeline projects in Jenkins 2.32.1 using a webhook. I want the gitlab push to trigger a build with parameters but the parameter value is null when it comes through so the build fails.

The gitlab webhook looks like:

`http://jenkins.server:8080/project/project-a/buildWithParameters?MYPARAM=foo`

In my pipeline project I echo the parameter value out with

`echo "MYPARAM: ${MYPARAM}"`

and it's not set to anything. Any ideas on where I've gone wrong?

**UPDATE**

The actual code I'm using in the pipeline is:

```
node {
    try {
        echo "VM_HOST: ${VM_HOST}"
        echo "VM_NAME: ${VM_NAME}"
        stage('checkout') {

            deleteDir()
            git 'http://git-server/project/automated-build.git'
        }
        stage('build') {

            bat 'powershell -nologo -file Remove-MyVM.ps1 -VMHostName %VM_HOST% -VMName "%VM_NAME%" -Verbose'
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The parameter `VM_HOST` has a default value but `VM_NAME` doesn't. In my Console output in Jenkins I can see:

```
[Pipeline] echo
VM_HOST: HyperVHost
[Pipeline] echo
VM_NAME:
```

Comment: Did you try: echo "MYPARAM: ${MYPARAM}"

Comment: Sorry yes that's exactly what I did, edited my question.

Comment: If you build this job manually from Jenkins, does printing MYPARAM work?

Comment: @PiotrDawidiuk Yes it works when invoking manually.

Comment: @MarkAllison Ok, how about setting a default value for a parameter? Building with webhook still return nothing? And what kind of type is the parameter? String?

Comment: @PiotrDawidiuk A default parameter works fine, see my update with the actual code used

Comment: @MarkAllison How do you pass token? Where is it in your URL - at the begging or at the end of GET params? If your URL is sth like `http://jenkins.server:8080/project/project-a/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&MYPARAM=foo`, change an order to `http://jenkins.server:8080/project/project-a/buildWithParameters?MYPARAM=foo&token=TOKEN`

Comment: I'm not setting that explicitly, I've put it in the Secret Token field on the hooks page in Gitlab. Underneath the field is this text: `Use this token to validate received payloads. It will be sent with the request in the X-Gitlab-Token HTTP header.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins Git Plugin does not receive posted Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867124/jenkins-git-plugin-does-not-receive-posted-parameters)

Answer (score 5):

I have been struggling with this for weeks. I had it working once, but I couldn't get it to work again, untill today. And the solution was mindblowingly obvious ofcourse...

Automatically for each pipeline job I ticked the following box:

> Build when a change is pushed to GitLab. GitLab CI Service URL:
>   http://jenkins.dev:8080/project/MyProject

Then from GitLab I used the webhook to trigger the above.
Like you I tried to add `/buildWithParameters` and tried many other things that didn't work.

The problem was, I ticked the wrong checkbox!
Since I trigger the build from a GitLab webhook, the above checkbox (build when a...) does not have to be checked at all.
What needs to be checked is:

> Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)

That checkbox provides you with a new URL:

> Use the following URL to trigger build remotely:
>   JENKINS_URL/job/MyProject/build?token=TOKEN_NAME or
>   /buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN_NAME

Like all the documentation I came along states and as you can see, the URL now no longer starts with `/project`, but with **`/job`** instead!

So **tick that box** and change your URL accordingly:

`http://jenkins.server:8080/**job**/project-a/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN_NAME&MYPARAM=foo`

Least I want to mention the token:
In the GitLab webhook there is a seperate field for "token", which states:

> Use this token to validate received payloads. It will be sent with the request in the X-Gitlab-Token HTTP header.

So, the token provided there will be sent along the request as a HTTP header.
This is the token which can be provided globally in the Jenkins setup.
The token you must provide in the Jenkins job when ticking the box `Use the following URL to trigger build remotely` must be send in the URL as GET parameter, just like the example shows.

***Final note:*** personally I have never got this working completely, because I don't get the Jenkins CSRF protection off my back. Disabling it gives me another error. However, hopefully the above does fix the problem for you and others.

Answer (score 2):

GitLab plugin does not allow you to pass arbitrary parameters. In their project there is an [open issue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin) for it that deserves to be upvoted.

My convoluted solution was to use the desired values for the push trigger as the default parameters of the job. Then I used the [Parameterized Scheduler plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler) to use other values in the scheduled executions.

The problem is that I got a bad usability for the job when it was manually run, since the default parameters were appropriate for the push hook.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here https://www.jittagornp.me/blog/jenkins-gitlab-webhook/

I verified it with Jenkins 2.263.1 and GitLab Community Edition 13.6.1

Your webhook url will look like
https://hunter:11a403302a4f01b9b4975c0ac27441a5cc@jenkinsservername.com/job/yourjenkinsproject/buildWithParameters?token=Aju9ryHUu6t7W8wLSeCWtY2bWjzQduYNPyY7B3gs&yourparam=yourvalue

"hunter" ist your username in Jenkins.
The following is the Jenkins API Token you have to create in your Jenkins User Managment independent of the project.

The last Token is the one you specify in the jenkins project options under "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)"

The last thing is to add your Parameter and value to the url with &param=value