# How trigger a job parameterized with webhook

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, webhooks

I am trying to trigger a job in Jenkins using a webhook in GitLab. But the job that I want to start is parameterized.

I made a little research looking for some plugins to make it easy like Gitlab hook plugin, but it doesn't work.

In some pages I found clues like *buildWithParameters?variable=value* but after testing this, the variable still blank.

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries, we discovered that our Gitlab environment had some issues of queueing process. Restarting the Gitlab was enough and the job started without problems.

Answer (score 1):

For me it didn't  work when I used **/buidWithParameters**, but when I changed to **/build** it did. 
See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/38037070/947784

Comment: Hello there. Thanks for reply. I tried to use /build passing parameters but no success. Jenkins couldn't found the parameters passed.

Comment: Did it trigger the job at all? Also, parameters are case sensitive, do you keep the same case?

Comment: Yes. The job is triggering and the parameters are ok but Jenkins still getting the variables blank

Comment: Do you use POST or GET? (it should be post), also do you use API token?

Comment: can you also share more of the webhook configuration? do you use gitlab plugin? how did you configure the integration?

Comment: We are using the gitlab plugin. Also we made some tests with the gitlab hook plugin but without success. And answer the other question, we use the secret token to link the webhook and the job in Jenkins.

We are thinking about that since last week and maybe this problem could be in Gitlab config. The Gitlab environment is problematic now. We are investigating the situation.